# Probability, Conditional Independence

Tags: probability

I need some help with determining conditional independence.  We have the data set below.

```
x                   0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1
y                   0       0       1       1       0       0       1       1
z                   0       1       0       1       0       1       0       1
P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)    0.05    0.2     0.05    0.05    0.15    0.3     0.1     0.1
```

I would prefer an explanation and/or hints to get me going with it (if you'll let me be so picky... I want to learn it).  The general definition for conditional independence is P(X, Y | Z) = P(X | Z) P(Y | Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill out the boxes from the table.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=1, Y=1 \mid Z=1) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=1,Y=1,Z=1)}{\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}}\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}}\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y,Z=1)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{0.1}{\Box+\Box+\Box+0.1}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(X=1 \mid Z=1) & = \dfrac{\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}}\mathsf P(X=1,Y=y, Z=1)}{\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}}\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}}\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y,Z=1)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\Box+0.1}{\Box+\Box+\Box+0.1}
\\[2ex]
P(Y=1 \mid Z=1) & = \dfrac{\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}}\mathsf P(X=x,Y=1, Z=1)}{\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}}\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y,Z=1)}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\Box+0.1}{\Box+\Box+\Box+0.1}
\end{align}$

Can you see where to get the values, and why?  It's the definition of conditional probability and the law of total probability.

Then does $\mathsf P(X=1,Y=1\mid Z=1) = \mathsf P(X=1\mid Z=1)\mathsf P(Y=1\mid Z=1)$ ?

Comment: Got it!  Thanks so much, this was perfect!